# map.forEachFeatureAtPixel not using latest map

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map inside a React app with vector tile features as well as an empty vector layer on top. When I click a vector tile feature, in `componentDidUpdate` I create a vector feature on the fly for editing and add it to my vector layer source.

This works but my select interaction is failing to select my vector feature this first time. Specifically, in `ol.interaction.Select.handleEvent`, `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` only finds the existing vector tile feature and not the newly created vector feature. The next time I click the vector feature, `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` correctly finds it and it gets selected.

I tried using

```
setTimeout(() => {
  selectInteraction.getFeatures().push(selectedFeature) 
}, 100)
```

after `vectorSource.add(vectorFeature)` and `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` correctly found my vector feature.

My guess is that even though I do `vectorSource.addFeature(vectorFeature)`, for some reason in the `select` handler, it's not seen by the `map` somehow (though when I get the vector source using map.getLayers, I can see my added feature). Is there an event that I can listen for once the map is fully up to date and I can call `select.getFeatures().push(vectorFeature)`?

Comment: Adding a feature will cause the map to re-render so it probably won't be available to `forEachFeatureAtPixel` until the `rendercomplete` event.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I fixed it by calling `map.renderSync()` after adding the feature.